# Keep receiving emails "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Eml Manager" but never used google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been receiving the following email every day for the last week and i have no idea why.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpkxa.png

When i click on the "click here" tag of the email it shows me this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m6y1.png

Full trigger id is VC0zHx0MTGeyznQ4MAG6Lw

I google this error and every answer i see relates to google scripts and that i need to desactivate some kind of trigger, but i never used google scripts and i can't seem to find what is triggering it.

Does anyone know what is happening and how can i solve it?

Thanks in advance!

[Without any filtering, it does not bring me any results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5S6A.png)
[Scripts emails April 7, 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJwa1.png)

Comment: Provide screenshot of [this page](https://script.google.com/home/triggers)

Comment: Do you have any addons?

Comment: Hello @CarolinaNoemiBernachea, can you confirm you don't have any script called "Eml Manager"? You can check my going [here](https://script.google.com/home/my). Cheers!

Comment: @TheMaster That image is the second one i uploaded in the post

Comment: @ale13 I have no projects, so it's empty

Comment: @Carolina No. 1. need the unfiltered picture. See the filter on the top? clear it. 2. Are you using the same Google account?

Comment: @TheMaster Hi!, 
I uploaded the photo with the trigger filter to show that even filtering through it, it did not return any results. But when I open in the place where you tell me, there is no filter, it is never filtered by anything and it never shows me that I have anything, it is a total mystery. And yes, obviously I am with the same gmail account where the emails arrive. And they keep coming, just yesterday, I had 10 emails ...I attached the photo where it shows that there are no filters.

Comment: if you clear(**x**) the `ID de  activador:VC...` on the top, does anything show up?

Comment: Check permissions: Do you see third party apps [here](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)?

Comment: @TheMaster Well, I just entered and took away the permissions of the latest apps. I will wait to see if I keep getting emails or not. Will keep you informed. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @CarolinaNoemiBernachea, are you still encountering the issue? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have added an add on "Eml Manager" and did not complete the "Permissions" the first time it runs. Just delete the add on or give it the permission. It should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deleted the only extension I had (Jitsi Meet), and for like 10 hours the problem was gone, but unfortunately it just came back and i did not install any other extension :(

Comment: the mail triggers once a day. So, you will get one mail for yesterday's failures. It will stop automatically. Don't worry

Comment: Actually, the mails arrive one per hour, I'm not lying, at the end of the day I had thousands of emails.
That particular day that I uninstalled that addon, for a period of 10 hours, I did not receive any email, and I thought "Oh, great, this was resolved", but then they came back, and only yesterday I had 7, 8 emails and still They keep coming. This is driving me crazy!


I will attach to the case, the photo of the emails only from yesterday