# Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Email Studio

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently got an email with this message claiming that Email Studio had issues. However, here's what's odd:

- The trigger id of the issue refers to a file non-existent on my Google Account.
- I haven't used Email Studio services in 2 years.
- I have never coded using Google Apps Script.
- When I checked files in Google Apps Script, there were no files I owned.
- However, there were files that were shared to me.

I found a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045730/keep-receiving-emails-summary-of-failures-for-google-apps-script-eml-manager) but the user seems to have not solve the problem

Right now I have gotten rid of all permissions in my Google account. Additionally I got rid of the shared files, despite the fact I know the owners of the shared files are trustworthy.

Is there any recommended path of action for this kind of problems? Is there a way to contact google about this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I was reviewing and apparently `Email Studio` is a 3rd party Add-on for Google workspace users. [This is](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/email_studio_for_gmail/60106804857) the listing page.

Google workspaces add-ons are based on Google Apps script, and they usually use some kind of simple trigger or installable triggers on their projects. This might have caused the email notification of the failure using the trigger. Maybe you added the add-on some time ago.

If you have a  Google Workspace account you can block the app access to the entire domain from `API control` by following the steps below: (You can access to the Google Documentation [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227))

1. Access to the Google Admin console.
2. Go to `Security` > `Access and data control` >  `API control.`

[image: API control]

3. Click on `Manage 3rd party app access.`

[image: Manage 3rd party app access]

4. Click on `+add filter`, and search for `Email Studio`.
5. Hover over the app and you will see an option called `Change access` at the end.
6. Select `Blocked`

If you do not have a Google Workspace account, you can simply removing the access to the app by accessing this [link](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Fsecurity%3Fhl%3Den&hl=en), search for the app and click on `Remove access`.

[image: Remove access]

You can also contact the support team for this app by accessing this [link](https://digitalinspiration.com/support)